# Java transferFrom will not transfer more than 16mb?

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

My java code will not transfer my 25mb file - it will stop at 16mb. I have tried changing `transferFrom` `1 << 24` to `48 & 31 & 8` nothing helped just made it worse. Any idea?

```
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(fileURL.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + fileName);
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
fos.close();
```

Comment: What was the logic behind `48 & 31 & 8`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long%29

Comment: @NPE I have read around google someone said 31 = up to 1 GB and 48 was double but they didn't work

Comment: @user1888440 I have looked into it before as well but it doesn't really helps me I didn't understand it any more help?

Comment: Working as designed. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you use `Java7` you can use the fancy `java.nio.file.Files` utils to copy.

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
 try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
    Files.copy(is, Paths.get("/tmp/output.tmp"));
 }
```

In case you not, you can use the open source utils- e.g. from Apache (search for `FileUtils` in Commons IO).

And in case you want to stick arround with your current solution, you can write it like this:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
    "/tmp/output2.tmp"));

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
int read = 0;
while ((read = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  bos.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
bos.close();
bis.close();
```

The intention is that you have to read until the end of the stream has been reached. That is why your `transferFrom` only downloads a limited amount of data as there is no guarantee that all the data will be transferred in one chunk.

Answer (score 0):

transferFrom is not guaranteed to complete in one invocation, especially with an URL. You need to call it in a loop.

Comment: Using Long.MAX_VALUE for the size parameter and call it in a loop.

Comment: @EJP, before you came to this answer, the font size was so big. then i said my first comment. now it lost its effect since the font was repaired :D